How to monitor ECS Fargate health check
I have an entirely message-driven workload running in ECS Fargate without a load balancer and with a health check defined in the container definition. For monitoring the application I would like to define a cloudwatch alarm that triggers whenever tasks get unhealthy.
For my HTTP workloads I use a metric alarm based on the UnhealthyHostCount metric to achieve this. How can I do it without a load balancer?

Fargate is a technology for running server applications, so of course it is relevant to programmers?! Why else would there even be an amazon-fargate tag in SO? I am a programmer and it is relevant to me, and I don't know what other Stack exchange I should post it to.

"Why else would there even be an amazon-fargate tag in SO?" - because anybody created it? To me, this question looks like it is better suited for serverfault.com.

@NicoHaase I think it's a valid question for SO since it's directly relates to AWS. However question could be improved with more details like task definition etc

@abdurrehman what makes you think that "directly relates to AWS" makes a question on-topic on SO? How is this problem related to programming?

@NicoHaase well we have a whole collective dedicated to AWS, so that makes me think asking question related AWS and it's services should be fine.

@NicoHaase the tag doesn't exist just because "anybody created it", the tag is part of the official AWS collective here on StackOverflow. There is no AWS collective on Serverfault. The rise of "DevOps" has made the line between "programming" and infrastructure admin tasks very blurry, and I personally don't see much value in trying to divide questions between these separate sites anymore. I certainly prefer to focus on helping people solve their problems, over focusing on which (overlapping) category their problems should be sorted into.

This is not a programming matter, as server management and load-balancing are not programming matters. Consider asking this question on https://serverfault.com where it would be on-topic.

@MarkB The tag was not created to be a part of a collective, it was created by someone who had a question about it. Also, there are no collectives on any sites other than Stack Overflow, so that argument is a red herring.

@TylerH The StackOverflow staff added that tag to the AWS Collective because they and Amazon wanted questions with that tag to be part of the collective. Yes it was probably created before the collective existed, but it was officially made part of the AWS collective when the collective was created. The fact is, StackOverflow is where the AWS collective exists. I don't see how that's a red herring.

@MarkB The SO staff added the tag to the collective because it's related to the collective. The staff didn't check to see whether any tags they added were on topic on the site at all (and frankly don't have that domain expertise to try in the first place). But arguing that a question is on-topic because there's a tag or a collective for it is a red herring and not how site scope/topicality rules work here.

I really don't get it, what is the value of this meta discussion here? Why we not focus on answering questions? :-(

There doesn't appear to be any metric reported to CloudWatch when container health checks fail. There also doesn't appear to be any events posted to EventBridge by ECS when a container health check fails. You could subscribe to the ECS EventBridge events, to know when a task is entering one of the PENDING, RUNNING or STOPPED states, but those don't really indicate the task health, and could end up spamming your inbox with too many notifications to be useful.
The official AWS documentation on container health checks recommends forwarding your health check command's output to CloudWatch Logs. If you did that, then you could configure a CloudWatch Log alarm based on specific text appearing in the log that indicates the health check has failed.
